# Select angular don´t show results

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application whre I want to get results into `select`, so I have it as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Register: </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in GetCatalogoPadre"></select>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

**AngularCtrl**

```
     function cargarCatalogo() {
         apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/", null,
            function (res) {
                $scope.Catalogos = res.data; 
            }, errorCatalogo);
```

**Controller**

```
namespace PortalDeTransporte.Web.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]    
    [RoutePrefix("api/Catalogo")]
    public class CatalogoRegistroController : ApiControllerBase
    {


    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCatalogoPadre")]

    public HttpResponseMessage GetCatalogoPadre(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
     //some code there for get results 
    }

            return response;
        });
    }
    }
```

Something extrange happens there, if I try to get results using postman with GET action like:

```
http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre
```

I get correct results as:

```
{
        "ID": "1",
        "Codigo": "BMX",
        "Nombre": "BANAMEX",
        "Padre": 0,
        "Catalogo": "BAN"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Codigo": "KNW",
        "Nombre": "KENWORTH",
        "Padre": 0,
        "Catalogo": "MAR"
    },
```

But them dont appear into select list, can someone view something wrong in code?. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

also ensure that you are calling the function on **`ng-init`**

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-init="cargarCatalogo()">
    <label>Register: </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
    <br />
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('thecontroller',function($scope){
       $scope.cargarCatalogo = function (){
            $scope.catalogos = [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Codigo": "BMX",
        "Nombre": "BANAMEX",
        "Padre": 0,
        "Catalogo": "BAN"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Codigo": "KNW",
        "Nombre": "KENWORTH",
        "Padre": 0,
        "Catalogo": "MAR"
    }];
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
          <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller='thecontroller' ng-init="cargarCatalogo()">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Register: </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedOption"       ng-options="choice.Codigo for choice in catalogos track by choice.ID">></select>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I change it as you say but I don´t  get results yet

Comment: you might have to change your function too as $scope.cargarCatalogo = function ()

Comment: but `res.data` get results as I want, why I would change it?

Comment: you also need to have ng-model, check the demo updated

Comment: Yes it works, but can you explian me why I need ng-model to results show up?